# Fluid swipe and scrolling 10.7 style

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, swipe, gestures, nsscrollview

I'm looking to add two finger "fluid swiping" to my app. Anyone who has used the week view in the Calendar app that comes with OSX will have seen what I'm trying to do.

I have a scroll view, and I want to be able to use swipe gestures and scrolling to move the content view in the horizontal axis of my NSScrollView, ie a day or a week.

The video from WWDC 2011 titled "Scrolling, Swiping, Dragging: Now with more animation" was quite useful, and looks like it will be able to explain what I want to do, but unfortunately the sample code for PictureSwiper isn't provided with the video.

I'm aware that a newer version of PictureSwiper is avaliable, but it uses NSPageController and I'm really looking for the older Lion 10.7 way of handling things as I can't use NSPageController. Is it still possible to find the old PictureSwiper somewhere?

If not could someone explain how the PictureSwiper sample on Lion worked? I'm aware of the App note https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html (search for "scrollWheel:") but that has only gone part of the way to explaining the kind of functionality I am after.

Many thanks for any help.
David.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to this for an answer I eventually used one of my "Developer Technical Support" queries that came with my paid Dev account to ask for the old code. A few days latter an Apple engineer emailed me the old Picture Swiper.

Now that I have seen the code the App note makes complete sense! Picture Swiper moves CALayers around, but in my case I just use NSClipView's scrollToPoint:.

Within the scroll handler I just do something like: (gestureAmount * columnWidth) + currentColumnIndexOffset.

Seems to work!

Comment: Do you still have the old Picture Swiper code? Could you share it with me?